# JavaScript Math Code Explanation

Tags: javascript, math

```
if(MathRScore > 29.9 && MathRScore < 34.9 ) MathScore = 10*Math.round((MathRScore*45/5+(535*35-580*30)/5)/10);
```

I've inherited this tiny line of exception code for a scoring algorithm I'm maintaining. I'm not sure what it does exactly. Can someone walk me through it?

Comment: Is there a specific thing on that line that you haven't been able to find documentation for? edit: I'm talking about JavaScript language/standard library documentation

Comment: It multiplies, divides, adds, subtracts and rounds some numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure why anybody would 10* and then round something. I'm wondering what exactly is the point of moving the decimal point if you're rounding up anyhow.

Comment: Thanks Felix, Got That - notice my question on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `MathRScore` is in the interval `(29.9, 34.9)` then set the `MathScore` to (in simplified form)

```
MathScore = 10*Math.round((MathRScore*9+265)/10)
```

By dividing by `10`, then using `Math.round` and then multiplying by `10` you will round to the nearest ten.

For example

```
10*Math.round(1111/10) = 10*Math.round(111.1) = 10*111 = 1110
```

Comment: Thanks @afsa! Clearly explained.

Answer (score 1):

if the value of MathRScore is between 30 and 34.8 , it will make the variable MathScore hold the value of 10 times the rounded value of all that stuff in the parenthesis.

Comment: "all that stuff in the parenthesis" is kind of vague, especially since the division by 10 is related to the multiplication by 10.

Answer (score 1):

If `MathRScore` is between 29.9 and 34.9, exclusive, then set `MathScore` to the value:

```
(MathRScore * 9) + 265
```

rounded to the nearest 10.

Beyond that, what this means can only be revealed by understanding how these scores work, and we can't tell you that.